# Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

проект написан был на html css js теперь хочу его переписать на react
есть основной контент
и popup элементы в файл App.js переношу весть html (что находиться в body) и когда парсер доходит до элементов popup выдает ошибку

```
Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?
```

```
<div className="page">
контент    
</div>
// popup
  <div className="popup popup_element_profile">
содержимое popup
</div>
```

элементы везде закрыты проверял...
что посмотреть посоветуете как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас в компоненте больше одного элемента, то да, нужно их обернуть в div или в React.Fragment

```
<>
    <div className="page">
<p>контент</p>    
</div>
<div>popup</div>
  <div className="popup popup_element_profile">
содержимое popup
</div>
</>
```

Comment: Вот тут можно почитать более подробно https://ru.reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html

Answer (score 0):

надо было сделать один общий div для всего

```
<div className="page">
контент    
<div className="popup popup_element_profile">
содержимое popup
</div>
</div>
```

и все сработало

Comment: ахха )) так я ж выше вам это и написал.

Comment: Да я только не доконца понял <></> значение этого тега спасибо тебе)